# how to solve mywebsite.com redirect to ww1.mywebsite.com?

Tags: url, domain

mywebsite.com redirects to a web site called ww1.mywebsite.com. Only www.mywebsite.com redirects to the desired host. How can I solve this problem and redirect mywebsite.com to the host which is in the www.mywebsite.com.

ww1.website.com tells that the domain may be for sale.

Comment: I've started the process to have this migrated to a more appropriate site. Before that happens I suggest that you add a lot more information to the question or they'll likely close it as unclear. Why is the redirection happening? Does it only happen on some computers? What are you running on your website? Etc...

Comment: It sounds to me as though it's a simple mistake made when you registered your domain. If that's the case, you need to check your website's DNS settings with your domain registrar. You need to create an A record for your domain without the preceding `www` and point it to the IP address of your server. There should already be an entry which points to your server with the preceding `www`. You should be able to change this record to exclude `www` (which should work for both) or you can simply add in the new record with the same IP. Create an additional AAAA record for the IPv6 IP if you have one.